# Help me understand Banners Component Toolbar Action (Joomla 3.3)

Tags: joomla-api, mvc

I'm learning Joomla development and I have so far been able to understand how to create subcontrollers, models, views, and layouts. Now I'm trying to understand how I can pass control from the subcontroller to a view when an admin clicks on the "New" toolbar icon. To do this I've been going through the Banners component that shipped with Joomla.

Here's where I'm a little bit lost and hope someone can make me understand.

**/views/banners/view.html.php** suggest that there is a subcontroller **banner** with the task **add**:

```
if (count($user->getAuthorisedCategories('com_banners', 'core.create')) > 0)
{
    JToolbarHelper::addNew('banner.add');
}
```

However, upon inspecting **/contollers/banner.php** I cannot find any **add** task assigned to the toolbar icon (or any of the task assigned to the menu for that matter).

Furthermore, clicking on the "New" icon redirects me to **index.php?option=com_banners&view=banner&layout=edit**

I just don't understand where the redirect is occuring because I cannot find any reference point to **banner.add**. Any advice on what the heck Joomla is doing in the background?

Comment: `class BannersControllerBanner extends JControllerForm` So you must find the `JControllerForm`. In Joomla3 it's under `/libraries/legacy/controller/form.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Fari, I was able to review the suggested Class to see what it is doing.